# Hive based UDF encryption/ decryption

Tags: hive, aes, user-defined-functions, xor, one-time-password

public class Saes extends UDF{

```
  public String evaluate(String encryptedinput) {
    String p= null;
    try {
            byte[] password = new String("abcdefghijklmnol").getBytes("UTF_8");
                // The password need to be 8, 16, 32 or 64 characters long to be used in AES encryption
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
        
        byte [] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedinput.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedmessageByte = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        byte [] secret = decryptedmessageByte;
        One1 o11 = new One1();
        char[] pad= o11.generate(secret.length);
        byte[] out = o11.decode(secret,pad);
        p = new String(out);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("error"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
   return p;
   }    
public class One1 {
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
 
  public char[] generate(int length) {
    char[] key = new char[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        key[i] = getRandUnicode();
    }

    return key;
 }
 private char getRandUnicode() {
    char c;

    while(!Character.isDefined(c = getRandomUnicode()));

    return c;
 }


private char getRandomUnicode() {
    return (char) (random.nextInt() & 0xFFFF);
 }

   public byte[] encode(byte[] data, char[] pad) {
    final byte[] encoded = new byte[data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        encoded[i] = (byte) (data[i] ^ pad[i]);
    }

    return encoded;
  }

   public byte[] decode(byte[] encoded, char[] pad) {
    final byte[] decoded = new byte[encoded.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length; i++) {
        decoded[i] = (byte) (encoded[i] ^ pad[i]);
    }

    return decoded;
  }

  }
```

i have hybrid encryption and decryption code. i want to execute as hive udf encryption/ decryption. after encryption the output used in Decryption . but decryption code gives null value in hybrid encryption (xor otp+aes) after encryption how we resolve the error.